# Full trips in complete graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected, finite, undirected, simple graph. A *full trip of $G$* is a map $f:\{1,\ldots,n\} \to V$ with the following properties:

1. for $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ we have $\{f(k),f(k+1)\}\in E$;
2. $\text{im}(f) = V$, and
3. for all $e\in E$ there is  $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $\{f(k),f(k+1)\}=e$.

Given $m\in\mathbb{N}$ what is the smallest value $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there is a full trip $f:\{1,\ldots,n\} \to V(K_m)$?

Comment: You are essentially asking about an Euler tour variant.  For $m$ odd, an Euler tour exists, so $n$ need be no more than one plus the number of edges $m \choose 2$.  For $m$ even and large, remove an exact matching, and the remainder then admits a n Euler tour, and you will need at most $ m-1 $ more edges to finish the full tour.  Gerhard "Probably Better Asked On Math.stackexchange" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: More generally, any such connected simple undirected graph requires at most twice the number of edges - 2. The proof is an easy induction on edge count:simply go down the new edge and back again, then back along the old tour. Star graphs realize this.  Perhaps a professional graph theorist can tell you the minimal number of backtracks in terms of some characteristic, probably number of vertices of odd degree.  Gerhard "Not A Professional Graph Theorist" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: Of course, $K_2$ is the exception among connected such graphs to the above statement.  Gerhard "One Edge Is Pretty Special" Paseman, 2017.03.29.